# Emacs GPG passphrase timeout

Tags: emacs, passwords, timeout, gnupg

How can I set up Emacs to re-request a passphrase when saving a `*.gpg` file only after a certain number of minutes have passed? While I know I can set Emacs up to request the passphrase only when opening, I would prefer a system where the last passphrase entry "times out" after, say, 5 minutes. I thought I saw something about this in the documentation before but seem unable to find it again and a web search turned up with nothing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using GPG 2.0.x then it's not Emacs caching the passphrase, it's `gpg-agent` and `pinentry`.  If that's the case then the passphrase caching time is in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and the setting you're looking for is `default-cache-ttl` followed by the number of seconds it will cache the passphrase for.  Set that to whatever you like.

If, however, you're using GPG 1.4.x then it might be gpg-agent (there's an option to include it when compiling) or it may be whichever interface you're using.  In this case Emacs and whichever version of the GnuPG interface is applicable for your version of Emacs (originally it was EasyPG, but it's been changing over the last few years).

Comment: Unless it's already changed again in trunk, I believe EasyPG is is the current library, and PGG is the obsoleted one.

Comment: In that case, the Emacs Wiki should have the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(epa) Caching Passphrases` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You might also look at `(pgg) Caching passphrase` from the now-obsolete (as of Emacs 24) `pgg` library, which is a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, My emacs doesn't have that entry in "epa" and the "pgg" idea didnt work.